# appending associative array to another array

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

```
$data=array();
$data[]= array('product_id'=>$this->input->post('product_id'),
                'quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity'),
                'unit'=>$this->input->post('unit'),
                'unit_rate'=>$this->input->post('unit_rate'));

                   $this->session->set_userdata('data',$data);
               $post_array['cart'][]=$this->session->userdata('data');
```

I want to append $data  to $post_array.  How do i do it with codeigniter??

**I am using this code for creating shopping cart where I want to store each product added by customer to session. And want to display all product that was added by user in separate table.**

Comment: Just simple try to assign it: `$post_array['cart'][] = $data`

Comment: and then?? How Do I access it using foreach loop??

Comment: this is going to be difficult at every step. my suggestion is to make a database table for the cart. when the first item is chosen, create a unique ID for the user and store that ID in the session. use that Unique ID in the cart table. new page - retrieve the Unique ID from session, use the Unique ID to return the items in the cart table.

Answer (score 2):

You can just simple assign your data to your cart array.

```
$post_array['cart'][] = $data;
```

Later, if you want to loop through that you can use this:

```
foreach ($post_array['cart'] as $item) {
    echo 'Id of product: ' . $item['product_id']."<br />";
    echo 'Quantity: ' . $item['quantity']."<br />";
    //and so on...
}
```

But I am assume, you want to add it to the session, not for the post.

**EDIT**

Base on OP comment. You are always overwriting your $_SESSION['data'] variable.
So add it as a new array:

```
//Set the data
$data[] = array('product_id' => $this->input->post('product_id'),
    'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'),
    'unit' => $this->input->post('unit'),
    'unit_rate' => $this->input->post('unit_rate'));
//Get the cart
$cart = $this->session->userdata('data');
//Add data to this temporary variable
$cart[] = $data;
//Set back the data
$this->session->set_userdata('data', $cart);

//Later, when you want to iterate through the cart:
foreach ($this->session->userdata('data') as $item) {
    echo 'Id of product: ' . $item['product_id'] . "<br />";
    echo 'Quantity: ' . $item['quantity'] . "<br />";
    //and so on...
}
```

Comment: You are right I want to add it in session. And right now I am exactly doing what you said, bit problem is that when user adds another product, second product row replaces first product row..

Comment: I tried it, but it again replacing old row with new one. Would i show you my full code?

Comment: Oh yes, that was my mistake. I've edited my code. Change this `$this->session->set_userdata('data', $data);` to this `$this->session->set_userdata('data', $cart);` I've added the data, what is only 1 item, instead the newly created cart.

Comment: I tried it, but now values are getting blank..Means rows are inserting but but with blank values